# Apache2 crash on boot, but not when started manually

Tags: apache, web, server, apache2

I got a wired problem that I don't understand at all:

I have a home server with an Apache2 installation on Ubuntu 18.04. My problem is that Apache2 keeps crashing on system reboot.

**systemctl status apache2** gives me:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
         └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-23 13:42:31 CEST; 3min 52s ago
Process: 1183 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1224 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mai 23 13:42:30 potato-server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
mai 23 13:42:30 potato-server systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
mai 23 13:42:31 potato-server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mai 23 13:42:31 potato-server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What's super weird is that when I do a manual **sudo systemctl start apache2**, the server starts. And apache2ctl configtest gives me:

```
Syntax OK
```

Any idea of where the problem can come from?

Answer (score 0):

I got some updates:

It seems that my bug is due to that fact I changed the group and user of Apache2 in **/etc/apache2/envvar**, according to this post: https://www.simplified.guide/apache/change-user-and-group

If I change back user and user group to www-data, it works again. However I would like to run Apache2 from an other user than www-data. Is this possible ?